# Script to check for files newer than argument, help using -nt

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make a script that shows files in the directory newer than one given as an argument, but I seem to be running into a problem. Currently I have:

```
for f in *; do 
    if [["$f" -nt "$1"]]; then 
        echo "$f"
    fi 
done
```

However this keeps giving me an error that commands cannot be found in reference to the files being iterated through. How can I fix the issues with this script?

Comment: Add a `set -x` to the top of your script?  The output should give you a pretty strong idea about what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need spaces around the `[[` and `]]`

```
for f in *; do
    if [[ "$f" -nt "$1" ]]; then
        echo "$f"
    fi
done
```

Without the spaces, you will get a series of "command not found" errors.  That is because the shell looks for a command by the name of `[["$f"` and cannot find it.  The command that you want to execute is `[[`.

#### Alternative

Without the need for looping:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -newer "$1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a space after the `[[` and another one before the `]]`. This is a carryover from `[`, which is traditionally an actual executable file (`/bin/[`, symlinked to `/bin/test`) - you needed a space to force it to be evaluated as `[` with `expression` arguments rather than `[expression`.

While `[[` is a bash keyword, it has a similar requirement.

It's also generally recommended to use the POSIX-compatible `[` in your scripts wherever possible. `[[` is not standard and therefore will not work on all POSIX shells.